# When trying to preview a theme - The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When trying to preview a new theme for my blog, this appears...

The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

I didn't receive an email though. I've tried deactivating all of my plugins and this didn't work. Any ideas? I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You should detect the error before do anything.

Turn on WP debug mode and you will see what error do you have:

In wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

More information about WP debugging: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

- Website/Admin is displaying "The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."

**This was my solution for our website. I only fixed enough issues for the admin page to start working again.**

This was all done after I fixed my initial site issues that crashed the entire site, addressed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65357857/14850513

After I made those fixes, the admin page was still giving the previously stated error message that you described, so here is how I fixed it. The following bullets are all of the error messages I faced and how I fixed them. This may not solve everyone's issues but these were the specific ones I faced.

- Go to the public.html/wp-config.php

  - go to the following line and change debugging to true

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false); #Change to true
```

This will show all of the errors that are causing the site to have issues. You must address them until it begins to function again. You will know because it will start working the next time you refresh.

- **ERROR 1:** Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated

  - Follow to each line listed and change '{}' to '[]'
- **ERROR 2:** Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /home1/seth/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/operations.class.php on line 2364

  - I open the php file at the problem line, I changed the term [continue;] to [break;]
- **ERROR 3:** "Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in xxx.php" on 258 line

  - Changed

```
public static function registerWidget($widgetName){
        add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("'.$widgetName.'");'));
    }
```

- to

```
public static function registerWidget($widgetName){
    add_action('widgets_init', function () use ($widgetName) {
        return register_widget($widgetName);
    });
}
```

- **ERROR 4:** Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings

  - the failing line was:

```
self::$arrMetaBoxes[] = $box;
```

- The fix is to add the following line right before it

```
self::$arrMetaBoxes = [];
```

My admin page started working at this point, but you may need to continue fixing errors until it begins to function properly again.